# How to have two subviews interact with each other?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, subview

I have a subview layering problem where I have a rotating arrow and a UIButton. The arrows rotate and the UIButton changes depending on the rotation of the arrows. The problem is that I need to have the UIButton clickable. At the moment the arrows rotate but the UIButton is not touchable. If I try `[self.view sendSubviewToBack:wheelControl];` the arrows are sent to the back and are no longer visible.

thanks for any help about how I might fix this.

[image]

Comment: Cant you just put the view with the button over the view with the arrows?

Comment: I think this may have fixed it:  [self.view addSubview:wheelControl];
 
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:myButton];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call

```
[theView bringSubviewToFront:theButton];
```

as the last call when laying out your subviews.